# Patch method using dio with xxx-www-form-urlencoded produces internal server error

Tags: flutter, dart

So, i have been trying to update user data using the patch method. The data should be of

> xxx-www-form-urlencoded

Also there are two additional headers required by laravel :

> Accept : application/vnd.api+json,
> Content-Type : application/vnd.api+json

But when i try to use the patch method in dio it produces 500 status code error.

This is the code for the patch request :

```
  Future<CustomerResponse> editCustomer(
      String id, AddCustomerModel addCustomerModel) async {
    print(addCustomerModel.toMap());
    var box = await Hive.openBox("tokenBox");
    String token = box.get("token");
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "name": addCustomerModel.name,
      "consumerType": addCustomerModel.consumerType,
      "corporateType": addCustomerModel.corporateType ?? "",
      "amc": addCustomerModel.amc,
      "amcDate": addCustomerModel.amcDate ?? "",
      "address": addCustomerModel.address,
      "phoneNo[]": addCustomerModel.phoneNo,
    });
    try {
      Response response = await dio.patch(
          "${Config.baseUrl}${Config.appFunctionRoute}/id",
          data: formData,
          options:
              Options(contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType, headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
            "Accept": "application/vnd.api+json",
            "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json"
          }));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return CustomerResponse.fromJson(response.data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return CustomerResponse();
  }


So , should i change something in the server side or there is something wrong from my end.
```